# How to log the stack return address of a function in c++

Tags: c++, c, logging, assembly, hook

I was wondering how to log the stack return address of a function?

If you log parameters like this:

```
int (WINAPI *pSend)(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags) = send;
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags);
```

// Below DllMain

```
int WINAPI MySend(SOCKET s, const char* buf, int len, int flags)
{
    fopen_s(&pSendLogFile, "C:\\SendLog.txt", "a+");
    fprintf(pSendLogFile, "%s\n", buf);
    fclose(pSendLogFile);
    return pSend(s, buf, len, flags);
}
```

Then how would I log the return address of Send?

Comment: By "return address" you mean the saved EIP?

Comment: Do you want to intercept the Send function of a win32 dll like Socks.dll or your own send function?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, so it's difficult to know if this is the correct answer. I'll assume you know what you're doing, but I would urge you to rethink your design.

With that said, check out the intrinsics `_ReturnAddress()` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/64ez38eh which will give you the address of the instruction that will be executed immediately after the function you call `_ReturnAddress()` from returns, and the `_AddressOfReturnAddress()` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s975zw7 which will give you the address where the return address is stored.

*Please* be sure to read the documentation *carefully* and to *understand* what the address you are getting back represents. And be **VERY CAREFUL** if you manipulate the return address, as things can (and will) go boom if you do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in a platform/compiler independent way. In Windows you can use StackWalk/StackWalk64 functions. I used them a couple of years ago. Provided you have debug info for the modules on the stack, you can get names of the functions.

For example look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680650(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What if this was inside a process which I was hooking? I do not have the debug info.

Comment: You need the debug info. In my experience even with debug info (.pdb files) you will have reasonable results on 90% of cases only. Without this info the rate drops to say 30%. Still this is better than nothing.

Comment: @Pepsi_1 If you can't recompile the program (you only have the binary, not the source code) and you don't have symbols, getting the function return addresses isn't a trivial thing. In order to get them you'd need to analyze the program's code or execute it more or less instruction by instruction so you can intercept the `call` and `ret` instructions. And even those aren't guaranteed to be there and to balance each other. They can be implemented with `jmp` and other instructions.